# Does Pickle.dumps and loads used for sending network data require change in byte order?

Tags: python, sockets

I know for integers one can use htonl and ntohl but what about pickle byte streams?

If I know that the next 150 bytes that are received are a pickle object, do I still have to reverse byte-order just in case one machine uses big-endian and the other is little-endian?

Comment: Never use `pickle`. It allows full remote code execution.

Comment: It does indeed unless one uses SSL for transferring pickle object. Do you have any alternatives to recommend that still can transfer full list or dictionary objects?

Comment: Even SSL only protects from middlemen, not compromised endpoints. Use `json` or something.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured out the answer.

> By default, the pickle data format uses a printable ASCII
>   representation.

since ASCII is a single byte representation the endianess does not matter.

Comment: That text is only for protocol 0, not for other protocols (which are still endian-neutral anyway) - 3 is the default for python3 (which you should be using for all new code). But seriously, never, **never** use `pickle`.